# Datatables with jQuery UI Tabs - Optimization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, resize

I have used the following link to successfully create various datatables for each jQuery UI Tab:

http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html

It works great!  Towards the end of the the second paragraph for the Preamble section, the author states that:

"An optimisation could be added to re-size only of the first showing of the table."

I would like to do that since each of my Tabs displays a Datatable and the constant resizing is interfering with the user experience.  It is OK if there is an initial delay on the first click of the tab, but it would be really good if the datatable does not need to be resized when the user switches back to the previously selected tab.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Bharat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a flag indicating whether you already did the resizing.